# Using WSO2 App-manager and EMM to cater both MDM and Non-MDM users

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I was trying to find a solution for using WSO2 App-manager and EMM so that both my MDM and Non-MDM users could use the store for installing apps.How can this be achieved and how WSO2 will differentiate MDM an Non-MDM users. And how many servers will be required such that both my MDM and Non-MDM users will use the store. Any help will really be helpful.

Comment: Could you explain the scenario how non-mdm users install apps?

Answer (score 1):

You Can archive the above just using the WSO2 EMM since the server have the APP Manager's Store functionality.
In order to differentiate MDM and non MDM users you have to define roles to represent MDM and NON-MDM users and provide permissions accordingly.

Plese follow the official documentation in order to manage users roles and permissions.

> https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Managing+Users+and+Roles